# Integral of continuous function

Tags: integration

If $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a continuous function.Then the integral
$$\int_{0}^{π} xf(\sin x) dx$$ is equivalent to. 
a)$$π\int_{0}^{π} f(\sin x) dx$$.       b)$$π\int_{0}^{π} f(\cos x) dx$$. 
c)$$\frac{π}{2} \int_{0}^{π} f(\sin x) dx$$.   d)$$\frac{π}{2} \int_{0}^{π} f(\cos x) dx$$.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could it be a) If $f(x)=1$ that would claim $\frac {\pi^2}2=\pi^2$, so no.
b) is ruled out by the same counterexample

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $\displaystyle I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx,$

$\displaystyle I=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$$\implies I+I=\int_a^b[f(x)+f(a+b-x)]\ dx$$